# Why is xsl:for-each-group missing some elements?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

The first `for-each-group` almost works. It finds everything that I need it to find, except some of the `sachbegriff` nodes (i.e. it finds 47, but one is missing etc.). When I a do a second pass (another for-each-group) explicitly asking for those nodes, I get them. (Of course, now I have some nodes twice and the order is messed up). Any ideas why I don't get them the first time around?

Tried with Saxon-HE .NET 9.x and 10.2 now.

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*" group-by="string()">
    <xsl:sort select="name()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
<xsl:for-each-group select="/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/sachbegriff" group-by="string()">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

SOLUTION/SOLVED based on Martin Honnen's answer/explanation below
XSLT 2.0

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*" 
    group-by="concat(name(), '|', string())">
    <xsl:sort select="name()" />
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

XSLT 3.0

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*" 
    composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), string()">
    <xsl:sort select="name()" />
    <xsl:variable name="name" select="name()"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

Comment: We can't really help you find the problem if you don't post your input/output and complete XSLT transformation. We need some context.

Comment: A bit long for you and me - even if I simplify it. I was hoping somebody has a clue with this little bit.

Comment: @Martin Honnen's answer below is was able to fix it like this:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*" group-by="string()">
    <xsl:sort select="name()" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="."/>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

groups all child elements of `/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]` by their string value and then pushes the first element in each group with `<xsl:apply-templates select="."/>` to a matching template. If some `sachbegriff` elements don't appear that way then because they are grouped together with other elements having the same string value but preceding them.

I can't tell which result you want, whether you want to really group all child elements by the string value but only process the first item in each group further. If you want to push all items in each group through to templates you can use `<xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>`. But usually, with grouping, people want to wrap and/or accumulate some items, so it doesn't seem likely to me you want that either.

I think it is better you show small, representative samples of input and wanted output, together with the criteria that map the input to the output.

Based on your edit to the question, if you really use XSLT 3, instead of `group-by="concat(name(), '|', string())"` I think you can use `composite="yes" group-by="node-name(), string()"` for the grouping.

Comment: @Martin Honnen. Thank you. That's it! Other elements with the same string value.

Comment: @mokko, see the edit, with XSLT 3, instead of concatenating two a more key values, you can also use a `composite` grouping key consisting in a sequence of values.

Comment: xslt 3.0 solution works as well. Feels a little faster!

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the `sachbegriff` elements from the first grouping, change

```xpath
/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*
```

to

```xpath
/museumPlusExport/sammlungsobjekt[@objId eq $id]/*[not(self::sachbegriff)]
```

Comment: yes, did that in the meantime. Thank you! Doesn't solve the problem though.

Comment: See if Martin Honnen's answer helps then.  I think he may have better interpreted what you've asked.